# Spinner data/values becomes multiple on tapping my created fragments

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, fragment

I have 4 fragments on my project and each of this fragments has a spinner.

Each time I tap/switch fragments, the spinner data/values is being repeated multiple times. Each spinner/fragments has the same corresponding content and value.

```
**--NOT TAP/FIRST LOAD--**
SUN
PLANET
STARS
COMET
**--TAP TWO OR MORE TIMES--**
SUN
PLANET
STARS
COMET
**SUN - data is repeated twice
**PLANET
**STARS
**COMET
***SUN - data is repeated thrice
***PLANET
***STARS
***COMET
```

Is there anything I missed? Is the fragment called multiple times?

Here is my code:

```
public class SolarSystem1 extends Fragment { - first fragment
public class SolarSystem2 extends Fragment { - second fragment
public class SolarSystem3 extends Fragment { - third fragment
public class SolarSystem4 extends Fragment { - fourth fragment

-----and so on-----

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
   Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  View myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_view, container, false);


  txtSystem = (Spinner) myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.system);

  system_options.add("SUN");
  system_options.add("PLANET");
  system_options.add("STARS");
  system_options.add("COMETS");

  ArrayAdapter<String> systemAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,system_options);
          systemAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
  systemAdapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);
  txtSystem.setAdapter(systemAdapter);
```

Hope you can help me.

Comment: so basically you have 4 spinners in 4 different fragments which show the same content correct? do all the 4 spinners have same name in layout/code?

Comment: yes same content. different names as (activity_solar1.xml, activity_solar2.xml, activity_solar3.xml, activity_solar4.xml)

Comment: any chance you can upload and share a demo project replicating this issue?

Comment: @ViVekH the snippet is already given above. is there any idea you can share it with me? thanks